# StratifiedShuffleSplit to get train test, valid data set

Tags: sklearn-pandas

Need to get train, test, validation dataset using `StratifiedShuffleSplit`.
Need to get
60% train, 20% test, 20% validation, so used `StratifiedShuffleSplit` twice to get three parts.

So did not use fraction to use `StratifiedShuffleSplit` twice, I set number of records in test.

```
s = [['a',1,'c'], ['AA',0,'CC'],['a',1,'c'],['AA',1,0],['a',1,'d'],['a',0,3],['AA',1,5],['AA',0,8],['a',1,7],['AA',0,8],['a',0,8],['AA',0,9]]

df = pd.DataFrame(s, columns=['input', 'Categories', 'labels'])
X = df[['input']]
Y = df['Categories']

from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit


ff = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=2, random_state=8, )
for train_idx, test_idx in ff.split(X, Y):
        X_train_temp=X[X.index.isin(train_idx)]
        Y_train_temp=Y[Y.index.isin(train_idx)]
        X_validation=X[X.index.isin(test_idx)]
        Y_validation=Y[Y.index.isin(test_idx)]
    
for train_idx, test_idx in ff.split(X_train_temp, Y_train_temp):
        
        X_train=X_train_temp[X_train_temp.index.isin(train_idx)]
        Y_train=Y_train_temp[Y_train_temp.index.isin(train_idx)]
        X_test=X_train_temp[X_train_temp.index.isin(test_idx)]
        Y_test=Y_train_temp[Y_train_temp.index.isin(test_idx)]
```

Somehow `X_train`, `X_test`, `X_validation` number of rows add up together equals to 11  which does not equal to total row number of X of 12.

Tried this on a larger dataset, somehow

```
 X_train.shape[0]+X_test.shape[0]+X_validation.shape[0].
```

is less than the original X.shape[0]. Do you know what might cause this?

Is there a more elegent way to do this train, test, validation using  `StratifiedShuffleSplit`?